# What's the difference between "Short URL", "Short Link", "Tiny URL" and "Tiny Link "?

Tags: usability-testing, terminology, wording

What is a good way to get the wording that most resonates with the user through user testing?

Context:
We're working on developing an URL shortener product, but we're not sure which of the 4 names best fits as a "high-frequency word" in our product.

Comment: 'Short URL' seems to be the most appropriate. 'Tiny URL' may have copyright issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could check Google search volumes for those phrases. It is also perfect case for easy A/B test. 
 
Most precise would be "Short URL", as "link" is broader term, and "tiny" is not only related to length. But to test is the best. :)

Answer (score 1):

TinyUrl is a trademarked term referring to a particular company - so "Short" Url" would be better. Oops. ShortUrl is also a company name. As is bitly as is ...

At this point it really doesn't matter except that "Url" seems to be more common than does "Link"

Any person or organization in the market would understand and be comfortable with any of the stated choices. At this point it's truly up to your marketing team. They could do some coffee house guerrilla A/B testing.